# What is truffle?

Tags: dapp-development, truffle, testing, framework, dapp-debugging

What is the [truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle) framework? Who can use it, who should use it?

And what are the benefits?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### What is Truffle?

**Truffle** is a development environment, testing framework and asset pipeline for Ethereum, aiming to make life as an Ethereum developer easier. It is one of the most widely used IDEs in the Ethereum community. Developers can use it to build and deploy DApps for testing purposes with many features that make it more attractive to users with a Web 3.0 dev background.

### Features:

- Automated contract testing with Mocha and Chai.
- A configurable build pipeline that supports both web apps and console
  apps.
- Generators for creating new contracts and tests (like rails generate)
- Instant rebuilding of assets during development (truffle watch)
- Console to easily work with your compiled contracts (truffle console)
- Script runner that lets you run JS/Coffee files with your contracts
  included (truffle exec)
- Contract compilation and deployment using the RPC client of your
  choice.
- Support for JavaScript, CoffeeScript, SASS, ES6 and JSX built-in.

### Who Should Use It?

Anyone who wants to dive into Ethereum development and needs a framework so they can better organize their DApp development assets and not have to worry about manually setting up a test environment.

Comment: How is Truffle an IDE? I thought it was more of a CLI framework

Comment: Truffle is now deprecated/sunset (Sep 2023).