# Need Some Basic Information related Ethereum

Tags: truffle, metamask, dapps, ganache

I'm newbie to block chaining and need help related truffle and related tools....
Q. Whats difference between truffle and ganache?

Q1. Is truffle/Ganache(Don't know difference) is server side EVM, I mean if I'm developing android Dapp then do I connect to it? Like if you are creating web app then it is easy as I have seen tutorials but I couldn't find any on android Dapp (which cover basics).

Q2.Whats use of meta Mask as I have seen it on youtube there were using it? what if do not use it.

THANKS IN ADVANCE ;) and please don't mind my silly questions, As I'm totally new to this stu

Comment: Please read [What's truffle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/what-is-truffle), [What's the difference between ganache and truffle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58093/difference-between-ganache-and-truffle), [Comparison of metamask with ganache](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55757/comparison-of-metamask-vs-ganache).

Answer (score 1):

Truffle is a development tool. It helps you to build and deploy smart contracts to an Ethereum based blockchain (such as the mainnet or in your case Ganache).

Ganache is a test blockchain that makes developing much, much easier. It runs locally on your own machine and truffle can interact with it as if it were the real blockchain. The 'block times' are instantaneous for example.

You could also use a 'live' testnet such as Ropsten which is the same as the mainnet except the 'Ether' on Rosten has no value. In this sense, you can use this run tests that don't costs a ton of money due to using real 'gas' on the mainnet.

Most people develop quite extensively on a test net before deploying to save development costs.

MetaMask is a wallet that helps you maintain and protect your private keys. It can connect to any Ethereum-based blockchain including mainnet and testnets (and probably Ganche).

Don't know anything about android dApps.